# Read XML value in JSON

Tags: json, tfs, azure-devops

i have a json file and an xml file. In xml file i have an element,name under root of publisher name and read the value of that element in json file. How to achieve this scenario.

JSON file

```
  {
    "manifestVersion": 1,
    "id": "build-my-json",
    "version": "0.6.4",
    "name": "Build Extension",
    "description": "Integrate",
    "publisher": "name"
  }
```

XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
</publishername>
   <name>Nitin</name>   
</publishername>
```

Basically i wanted to make publisher name dynamically for TFS extension.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are publish extensions through build, you can add PowerShell task to update the publisher per to the XML file:

PowerShell script:

```
param(
    [string]$xmlfile,
    [string]$jsonfile
)
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $xmlfile)
$publisher=$xml.publishername.name
Write-Output $publisher
$a = Get-Content $jsonfile -raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$a.publisher=$publisher
$a | ConvertTo-Json  | set-content $jsonfile
```

Arguments: `-xmlfile [xml file] -jsonfile [json file]`

Update:

It is not supported to update the publisher during the extension publish time. I recommend you publish extension through build/release.

Comment: Thanks @strain-MSFT i not publish any extension from build i publish my VSTS extension and i just want to change my publisher name through xml file runtime

Comment: @NitinParashar During the publish runtime?

Comment: @strain-MSFT yes

Comment: @NitinParashar No, it is not supported. (I updated my answer)

Comment: @NitinParashar I recommend you publish extension through build/release. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jessehouwing.jessehouwing-vsts-extension-tasks